# General form for $A_n = A_{n - 1} + A_{n - 2} + 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

I have tried to solve the following recurrence but have not made any real progress at all:
$$A_n = A_{n - 1} + A_{n - 2} + 1, A_0 = 1, A_1 = 2.$$
As to what I have tried, I have tried defining $\{A_n\}$ in terms of a new subsequence $\{B_n\}$, but apparently haven't been able to do this particularly successfully - I unfortunately do not have much experience with this sort of thing, and will really appreciate any sort of help.

Comment: I suggest introducing $B_n=A_n+1$. then the relation to study is $B_n=B_{n-1}+B_{n-2}$ without that pesky nonhomogeneous term. If you solve the relation for $B$ you can shift back to $A$.

Comment: Try defining the power series $\Phi(x)=\sum_{n} B_n x^n$.

Answer (score 3):

It may not be the most elegant way, but you can solve second-order linear difference equations in essentially the same way you solve second order linear differential equations. You  need to find a homogeneous and particular solution. The homogeneous solution $A^{(h)}_n$ satisfies the recursive relationship $$A^{(h)}_n - A^{(h)}_{n-1} - A^{(h)}_{n-2} = 0.$$ We arrive at this by moving all the $A$ terms over to one side and setting the other side to $0$. For the homogeneous solution, try $A^{(h)}_n = \lambda^n$. Inserting this gives $$\lambda^n - \lambda^{n-1} - \lambda^{n-2} = 0 \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, \lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 = 0 \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, \lambda = \frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}.$$ Any linear combination of homogeneous solutions is still a homogeneous solution, so we have $$A^{(h)}_n = C_1 \left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n + C_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n,$$ for arbitrary constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.

For the particular solution, use something like the method of undetermined coefficients. For the equation $$A^{(p)}_n - A^{(p)}_{n-1} - A^{(p)}_{n-2} = 1,$$ the right hand side is a zeroth order polynomial in $n$, so guess $A^{(p)}_n = \alpha$, constant (which is an arbitrary zeroth order polynomial in $n$). Plugging this in gives $$\alpha - \alpha - \alpha = 1 \,\,\,\, \implies \,\,\,\, \alpha = -1.$$

Thus the full solution is $$A_n = -1 + C_1 \left(\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n + C_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}\right)^n$$ Now determine the constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ using your "initial conditions" $A_0 = 1$ and $A_1 = 2$.